# declare an array in VBA, exception

Tags: vba

in the following piece of code, VBA tells me that `boundary` has to be a constant on the `Dim vals(1 To boundary) As Variant` line. This is the first time I see this. What's happening here ?

```
Dim boundary As Integer
boundary = distrib.Count

Dim vals(1 To boundary) As Variant
For i = 1 To boundary
    vals(i) = distrib(i, 3) + distrib(i, 4)
Next i
```

`distrib` is an array declared as variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a fixed size array with a non-constant value; instead you need to declare it as a dynamic array (by omitting a size) then redimension it to your desired bounds;

```
Dim vals() As Variant
ReDim vals(1 To boundary)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign data in the same operation as declaring a variable. Try a `Redim` instead

```
Dim boundary As Long
boundary = 10
Dim vals() As Variant
ReDim vals(1 To boundary)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can'd declare an array initially with variable bounds, however you can ReDim then to variables:

```
Dim boundary As Integer
boundary = distrib.Count

Dim vals() as Variant
ReDim vals(1 To boundary)
For i = 1 To boundary
    vals(i) = distrib(i, 3) + distrib(i, 4)
Next i
```